# Need to loop out 15 - 30 knots

Tags: javascript

I have the code so it will print out 30 knots; however I need 15-30knots and I am not sure what i am missing.

```
package knots;

/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class Knots {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int m = 0; //place holder for miles
        int k; //place holder for KM
        int knot; //Knots
        int v; //holds knots


        for (knot = 15; knot < 30; ++knot)

            m = (int) (1.151 * knot);
            k = (int) (1.852 * knot);
            v = knot;
            System.out.println(v + " knots is "  + m + " miles and " + k + " kilometers");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `{...}` after for to make it loop. Else its going loop only the first line `m = (int) (1.151 * knot);` and rest of the lines will be executed after the loop ends.

```
for (knot = 15; knot < 30; ++knot)
{
    m = (int) (1.151 * knot);
    k = (int) (1.852 * knot);
    v = knot;
    System.out.println(v + " knots is "  + m + " miles and " + k + " kilometers");
}
```